# event click in table dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table, which always when I click add it adds some fields and two actions one to change and another to remove, so when I click on these actions I want to fired a jquery event, but when those lines are added dynamically this does not work, only works when I put them statically (in red) as I do so my dynamic lines have the same effect as static?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.btnAlterarContato').click(function() {
    alert('Click in Change');
    return false;
  });

  $('.btnRemoverContato').click(function() {
    alert('Remove in Change');
    return false;
  });


  $('#btnADD').click(function() {

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";



    cols += '<td>';

    cols += '<a class="btnRemoverContato btnPadraoTabela"  href="" > Remover</a>'
    cols += '<a class="btnAlterarContato btnPadraoTabela" href="">   Alterar</a>'
    cols += '</td>';




    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#contatos").append(newRow);



  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<button id="btnADD"> Add </button>


<table id="contatos" class="table table-hover table-sm ">
  <thead>
    <tr>


      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <td>
      <a style="color:red;" class='btnRemoverContato btnPadraoTabela' href=""> Remover</a>
      <a style="color:red;" class='btnAlterarContato btnPadraoTabela' href="">   Alterar</a>
    </td>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [jQuery Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click','.btnAlterarContato',function() {
   alert('Click in Change');
   return false;
});

$(document).on('click','.btnRemoverContato',function() {
   alert('Remove in Change');
   return false;
});
```

***Description:-***

> This above code will work because it added event listener, to a parent
>   element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector,
>   ***whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.***

Comment: @BrunoAparecidodaSilva it worked because you are hooking an event to the document (which works for any element that matches the selection), not a specific element that has to exist before the script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the follow:

Tags statics are in same DOM reference,while those added dynamically are in other reference DOM.

Use [On Event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) jquery

Ex:

```
$(document).on('click','.btnAlterarContato',function(){
//your code here
});

$(document).on('click','.btnRemoverContato',function(){
//your code here
});
```

or use a event onclick in tag calling a function

```
<a style="color:red;" class='btnRemoverContato btnPadraoTabela' href="" onclick="nameFunction()"> Remover</a>

function nameFunction(){
//your code here
}
```

sry my english :D